# How to get given value to create method of Sequelize in a hook

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

This is my method for user

```
const user = await User.create({ ...req.body, totp_active: 'N', is_active: 'Y' });
```

And i want to get this given object to create method in a hook to User Model like

```
User.addHook('beforeValidate', function(user, options) {
    console.log('given object');
});
```

Comment: Do you mean you want to get the js plain object `{ ...req.body, totp_active: 'N', is_active: 'Y' }`?

Comment: Yes i want this plan object in hook function

Comment: Can you tell me why you want to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Model.toJSON()` to convert the instance to a JSON representation. You will get js plain object.

E.g.

```js
import { sequelize } from '../../db';
import { Model, DataTypes } from 'sequelize';

class User extends Model {}
User.init(
  {
    email: DataTypes.STRING,
    totp_active: DataTypes.STRING,
    is_active: DataTypes.STRING,
  },
  { sequelize, tableName: 'users', modelName: 'user' },
);
User.addHook('beforeValidate', function(user, options) {
  const obj = user.toJSON();
  delete obj['id'];
  console.log(obj);
});

(async function() {
  try {
    await sequelize.sync({ force: true });
    const req = { body: { email: 'example@gmail.com' } };
    await User.create({ ...req.body, totp_active: 'N', is_active: 'Y' });
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  } finally {
    await sequelize.close();
  }
})();
```

The execution result:

```sh
Executing (default): DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "users" CASCADE;
Executing (default): DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "users" CASCADE;
Executing (default): CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "users" ("id"   SERIAL , "email" VARCHAR(255), "totp_active" VARCHAR(255), "is_active" VARCHAR(255), PRIMARY KEY ("id"));
Executing (default): SELECT i.relname AS name, ix.indisprimary AS primary, ix.indisunique AS unique, ix.indkey AS indkey, array_agg(a.attnum) as column_indexes, array_agg(a.attname) AS column_names, pg_get_indexdef(ix.indexrelid) AS definition FROM pg_class t, pg_class i, pg_index ix, pg_attribute a WHERE t.oid = ix.indrelid AND i.oid = ix.indexrelid AND a.attrelid = t.oid AND t.relkind = 'r' and t.relname = 'users' GROUP BY i.relname, ix.indexrelid, ix.indisprimary, ix.indisunique, ix.indkey ORDER BY i.relname;
{ email: 'example@gmail.com', totp_active: 'N', is_active: 'Y' }
Executing (default): INSERT INTO "users" ("id","email","totp_active","is_active") VALUES (DEFAULT,$1,$2,$3) RETURNING *;
```